# How to add indentation to data on a python web page?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

I have the following code that is supposed to indent the data like this:

```
Searching for: 5456
    Child Unit ID: 32455
    Unit Location: Test
```

I have written the code to achieve this indentation but for some reason the indentation is not working when I am viewing it on web page. This python code is being used in `Flask`

Code:

```
temp_storage = {}
list_output = []

def printingData(Unit, increaseSpaceLength, source="."):
    theSpace = '       '
    spaceLength = theSpace*increaseSpaceLength
    list_output.append(f"{spaceLength}Searching for {Unit}:\n")
    for path in glob.glob(os.path.join(source,"x*.xml")):
        theDocument = temp_storage.setdefault(path, ET.parse(path).getroot())       
        if(theDocument.get("ID")== Unit):
            theSpot = theDocument.findall('.//xTest[@Type="Unit"]')
            if len(theSpot) == 0:
                list_output.append(f'{spaceLength}No sub Units found for {Unit}\n')
            else:
                increaseSpaceLength +=1
                spaceLength = theSpace*increaseSpaceLength
                for unit_element in theSpot:
                    unit_id = unit_element.get("Unit")
                    location = unit_element.get("Name")
                    if unit_id != "":
                        list_output.append(f'{spaceLength}Child Unit ID:{unit_id}\n')
                        list_output.append(f'{spaceLength}Unit Location:{location}\n')
                        printingData(unit_id, increaseSpaceLength= increaseSpaceLength+1,source=source)
    return list_output
```

Flask:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.form.get('name')
        
        return_string = printingData(name, source=r"C:/.../.../")
        return render_template('my-form.html', result=return_string)
    return render_template('my-form.html', result='')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

HTML:

```
<body>   
   <ol>  
       <!-- For loop logic of jinja2 template -->   
       {%for i in result%}   
       <li>{{i}}</li>   
       {%endfor%}   
   </ol>   
</body>
```

This is the current output:

```
Searching for: 5456
Child Unit ID: 32455
Unit Location: Test
```

I am not exactly sure what I am missing in order for the indentation to work.

Comment: What's the current output?

Comment: @Swifty added the current output. It's not indenting the data.

Comment: I tested it (with some dummy data), and the strings in `list_output` feature the desired leading spaces.

Comment: @Swifty This code is being used along with Flask. Do you think that could be the reason why the indentation is not working? I have added my Flask portion of the code into the question.

Comment: Afaik, it's an html problem, not a Python one; try replacing the spaces in your script with `'&nbsp'`s. On a side note, you should have tested your script (`print` statements, for example, work great), determined that `list_output` was correct and pinpointed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem comes down to html not displaying leading spaces as you expect. Try replacing `theSpace = '       '` with:

```
theSpace = '&nbsp;' * 7
```